# Android gradle: https://maven.fabric.io/public not working with proxy

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, twitter-fabric

### Gradle project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

}
```

### Gradle module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    // enter code
}

dependencies {
    // enter code
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

I can't build gradle in android my project. Network with proxy. Android studio has set proxy.

### Error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

Please...! 
I am new begin Android. 
Thanks so much!